# Binarize data frame values based upon a column value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
+---------+-------------+------------+------------+
| hello   | val1        | val2       | val3       |
+---------+-------------+------------+------------+
| 1.024   | -10.764779  | -8.230176  | -5.689302  |
| 16      | -15.772744  | -10.794013 | -5.79148   |
| 1.024   | -18.4738    | -13.935423 | -9.392713  |
| 0.064   | -11.642506  | -9.711523  | -7.772969  |
| 1.024   | -4.185368   | -2.094441  | 0.048861   |
+---------+-------------+------------+------------+
```

Let this dataframe be `df`. This is the operation I essentially would like to do

```
values = ["val1", "val2", "val3"]
for ind in df.index:
    hello = df.loc[ind, "hello"]
    for name in values:
        df.loc[ind, name] = (df.loc[ind, name] >= hello)
```

Essentially for every row `i` and column `j`, if `val_j` is less than `hello_i`, then `val_j = False`, otherwise `val_j = True`

This is obviously not vectorized, and with my giant version of this table on my computer, my computer is having trouble performing these alterations.

What's the vectorized version of the operation above?

Comment: Is there any reason for doing these manipulations `row-wise`, instead of `column-wise`? To me it seems that you can calculate the whole column val_j_binary in one go.

Comment: @cel Column wise? We're evaluating a cell to be `True` or `False` depending on the value on the row, not the column. I'm not sure what your question is.

Comment: Sorry are you overwriting the existing columns with True or False if they are greater than or equal to the hello column?

Comment: @EdChum: Yes I am. Sorry, I didn't understand your earlier comment about how this could be faster if it were a `column-wise` manipulation until it hit me this morning.

Comment: @hlin117 my answer shows a different approach which is significantly faster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be quicker to test the entire series against the hello series:

```
In [268]:

val_cols = [col for col in df if 'val' in col]
for col in val_cols:
    df[col] = df[col] >= df['hello']
df    
Out[268]:
    hello   val1   val2   val3
0   1.024  False  False  False
1  16.000  False  False  False
2   1.024  False  False  False
3   0.064  False  False  False
4   1.024  False  False  False
```

If we compare the performance:

```
In [273]:

%%timeit
val_cols = [col for col in df if 'val' in col]
for col in val_cols:
    df[col] = df[col] >= df['hello']
df    
1000 loops, best of 3: 630 µs per loop
In [275]:

%%timeit
column_names = [name for name in df.columns if "val" in name]
binarized = df.apply(lambda row : row[column_names] >= row["hello"], axis=1)
df[binarized.columns] = binarized
df
100 loops, best of 3: 6.17 ms per loop
```

We see that my method is 10x faster as it is vectorised, your method is essentially looping over each row

Comment: Never did I know that a `for` loop in pandas would be faster than one of its built in functions. Thanks a lot.

Comment: The for loop isn't the key here, the main point is that we're operating on the entire series, you passed `axis=1` so in effect you a doing a for loop on each entry for each row

Comment: It's possible that this would be a slower method if there were less rows than columns. But yes, your comment about `axis=1` is correct.

Comment: If I wanted to store `0` or `1` instead of `False` or `True`, how would I do this?

Comment: Nevermind. `df[val_cols] = df[val_cols].astype(int)` did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Some experimentation led me to this

```
column_names = [name for name in df.columns if "val" in name]
binarized = df.apply(lambda row : row[column_names] >= row["hello"], axis=1)
df[binarized.columns] = binarized
```

This works.